# Would this floating colony on Saturn actually work?

Tags: technology, planets

I'm basically working on a concept for a floating colony on Saturn, like a cloud city.

Saturn is about 75% Hydrogen and 25% helium, so if a balloon with pure hydrogen were to be used, hypothetically, it would probably provide around 25% lift in the atmosphere. A pure hot-hydrogen balloon attached to a colony would be somewhat of a great idea.

A solar concentrator would be used to concentrate solar rays into a small cone so as to increase solar energy efficiency on trans-terrestrial planets. The same could be used to apply to algae and plants for oxygen supply and plants.

Or the immense turbulence of Saturn's atmosphere could be harvested for energy via windmills. The wind speeds on Saturn are about 1,800 kmph, so electricity and heating the hydrogen gas balloon for lift shouldn't be a problem.

According to Wikipedia, Saturn has 10.44 m/s acceleration of gravity, just a slight bit more than Earth's. So shouldn't the colony be floating in the air due to increased buoyancy?

[image]

Please give me your opinions on whether a floating colony on Saturn would work or not.

Comment: Welcome Furious. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. We like focused questions here which present a problem to be solved, soliciting opinions would be off-topic. Can you [edit] to ask a question which presents us a problem to solve. (You might bear in mind that the actual lift you get from this arrangement will be minimal).

Comment: The edit has given us multiple issues to evaluate (feasibility of: getting sufficient lift from hydrogen there, maglev-loops on Saturn, cones for focusing light and growing algae. Single focused questions. Could you pare it down to a single question. You can always as separate questions each in their own thread, hyperlinking them.

Comment: @Furi - welcome.  i think the idea is sold but there is too much in this one question.   There are actually 3 questions which is why I voted to close.   Prune it back to "How best to suspend a colony in the upper atmosphere of Saturn".    I am hoping to then read a reprise of Daron's FLAPPOPOLIS flying city scheme, adapted for the Saturnalia.  Save the other stuff for other questions.  We need grist for the mill!

Comment: Hello Furious. Per the [help], our primary job is to help you develop and consistently use rules for an imaginary world of your own creation. Asking whether or not a particular idea "could actually work" (presumably in the Real World) isn't what we do (see [Advice concerning questions: asking HOW to implement a technological procedure or device](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8273/40609)). You have a fine idea! Do you need further help developing it? If not, there isn't a question here.

Comment: *"According to Wikipedia, Saturn has 10.44 m/s acceleration of gravity, just a slight bit more than Earth's. So shouldn't the colony be floating in the air due to increased buoyancy?"* - This does not follow. Please look-up buoyancy (as it relates to fluid densities - and weight/volume of balloons), then re-work your question, you can then ask one which requires us to solve a problem rather than express an opinion.

Answer (score 4):

### This is a tough one.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn) cites a figure of 3.25% for the amount of helium in Saturn's atmosphere - to me 25% sounds too high.  If you *had* 25% helium, then the all-hydrogen atmosphere would be 20% lighter.  Bear in mind that hydrogen is much lighter than oxygen, so it can lift much less at atmospheric pressure - but you likely wish to go much deeper, probably 10-20 atmospheres of pressure, to reach probable clouds of water and comfortable room temperature.  So the balloon would be order-of-magnitude comparable to a hot air balloon in your scenario, but the low amount of helium makes it less effective.  Nonetheless, you can still *heat* the hydrogen to make it more comparable, perhaps with your solar rays.

Another issue is that the water clouds haven't been well imaged because there are other clouds in the way, so getting solar power could be hard.  You might want a higher level aircraft beaming power down.  Alternatively, the immense turbulence of Saturn's atmosphere could be a source of power.

But -- this is the biggest issue.  Saturn's winds are five times faster than an Earthly hurricane  It's hard to get an intuitive sense of how this plays out at a small scale, though - the bands of alternating wind direction are vastly larger than Earth.  Planes can *fly* into hurricanes, and do for research, but at least, expect a skeptical response for a large hydrogen balloon.  Maybe you could use some aerogel that is incredibly light and tough so that your balloon can break apart and reconstitute itself continually.

I don't want to discourage you, but personally I prefer flat graphene-based organisms that use the passing air currents to extract electricity as they are stretched, while controlling their surface ripples to gain elevation like a glider...

Comment: You're also dealing with only about 1% of the sunlight per unit area that Earth gets out by Saturn, making solar power a very difficult sell.